# Dates Displayed yyyy-mm-ddd In VB.Net TextBox From SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I have a problem on one computer running my application.

The application (vb.net) connects to SQL Server and one of the bound fields is a date.

On 4 computers it is displayed correctly (dd/mm/yyyy). However on one computer it is displayed as it is in Management Studio which is yyyy-mm-dd.

All 5 computers login with the same username and this username's language has been set to British in Mangement Studio.

I have also checked the date/language settings in Windows XP and they are the same on all computers.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the reversed date on the one computer?

Comment: Uh, why don't you use formatting functions in VB.net to always display the date as you deem "correct" instead of relying on local settings etc.?

Comment: I know you say you've checked this but are you sure that the date setting is specifically dd/MM/yyyy on that machine and not just set to UK?

Comment: MSDN: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: So is it incorrect in the app and/or just SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your responses and apologies for my later reply. I should have been clearer in my post. The data is filled into a datatable and the date field bound to a textbox. I have now found that you can instruct the field to format when binding however this still doesn't work on the one computer. I am puzzled!

Comment: This is the code I use for the binding. It works on 4 computers but the 5th computer it does not! PostDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", JobsData, "Post Date", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, DBNull.Value, "dd-MM-yyyy")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using the [Binding.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx) event.

Thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` method to display it correctly.